# How to round to nearest doubling factor of 32?

Tags: javascript, math, binary

I have a bunch of bins which double in size, starting from size 32. The bins are divided in half and added to the lower bin, but this isn't important for the question. I am currently hardcoding a "max" `16777216` which is the size of the largest bin.

```
let bins = [
  [], // 1 = 32
  [], // 2 = 64
  [], // 3 = 128
  [], // 4 = 256
  [], // 5 = 512
  [], // 6 = 1024
  [], // 7 = 2048
  [], // 8 = 4096
  [], // 9 = 8192
  [], // 10 = 16384
  [], // 11 = 32768
  [], // 12 = 65536
  [], // 13 = 131072
  [], // 14 = 262144
  [], // 15 = 524288
  [], // 16 = 1048576
  [], // 17 = 2097152
  [], // 18 = 4194304
  [], // 19 = 8388608
  [0], // 20 = 16777216
```

I would like to dynamically determine the number of bins based on the available memory on the platform, as a factor of 32. So if there was 24 TB of available memory on the machine, that is 1.92e+14 bits, or 6e+12 32-bit chunks. So I would round that number up to the nearest double factor multiple of 32, following this same pattern of how the numbers grow.

How do I do this programmatically with a generic equation? I gathered these numbers by doing this manually:

```
a = 1 * 32
b = a * 2
c = b * 2
d = c * 2
...
```

1. How do I do this with a generic equation?
2. How do I round up efficiently to the nearest one of these numbers?

Comment: No `(i * 32) + (i * 32 * (2 * (i - 1)))` with `i == 19` gives 22496 which isn't in the list.

Comment: I think it is 2**(4+i), where with ** I mean `power of`

Comment: This seems to be fitting well: `32 * (2^(i-1))` where ^ = power of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const smallestBin = n => {
  if(n <= 32) return 32;
  let size = 5;
  for(let x = Math.trunc(n/32); x > 0; x = Math.trunc(x/2), size++) { }
  size = 2**size;
  return size == n*2 ? n : size;
};
```

Note that we don't use bit-wise operators because they're limited to 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `32 * 2 * 2 * 2...` you are multiplying 32 by a certain power of 2, or basically:

```
32 * 2^i
```

Now, since in your example `i` starts from 1. the correct equation is actually:

```
16 * 2^i
```

And since 16 is also a power of 2, you can just write this as:

```
2^4 * 2^i
```

Which is equal to:

```
2^(4+i)
```

If you now have a random number, how do you round it up to the nearest power of 2? This is basically calculating the logarithm (base 2) of your number, then round the result to the next integer.
This integer value is the exponent of the nearest power of two (rounding up).

If you want the nearest power of 2, this is just: `2^result`. So the complete equation is:

```
2^round(log_2(num))
```

In javascript, you can do this with:

```
2**Math.ceil(Math.log2(num))
```

If you need your index `i`, remember that your numbers are 2^(4+i), so just subtract 4 from `round(log_2(num))` and you get `i`

Comment: Haha I knew it was something simple! What about then, I just need to round to the nearest power of 2?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. All of these numbers are already power of 2

Comment: I mean, given I have some arbitrary number (the max memory size for a platform), how I find the correct bin by rounding that number up.

Comment: I edited the answer to correct a minor mistake. I hope it answers also your last question

Comment: Sorry, had to make a bunch of edits...I'm not sure if you want the nearest power of 2, or if you want the index of your array. In the answer should be explained how to get both